# Adding styles in rich text Touch ui multifield

Tags: aem, aem-6

I was trying to create a multifield touch ui text component in AEM 6.2.
I created it by adding a field with the following resource type:

```
<test
   jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
   sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext"
   fieldLabel="Touch Ui Text"
   name="./test"
   renderReadOnly="{Boolean}true"/>
```

It worked.But I have to add styles as a plugin in my mutifield text component which I am unable to do.
How to add the plugins just like we add rte plugins in classic ui?
I need to provide various styles in the rich text editor as part of multifield.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the option to use custom styles in the Rich Text Editor was [removed in Touch UI, as per the AEM 6.0 documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/operations/page-authoring/rich-text-editor.html#Plugins%20and%20their%20Features%20-%20Touch-optimized%20UI).

> The following plugin/feature combinations are not supported with the touch-optimized UI:
>
> - edit
> - image
> - sourceedit
> - **styles**
> - table

Thankfully, **they're back in AEM 6.2**. I'm not sure about 6.1, they're probably also supported.

The documentation for AEM 6.2 [describes the steps necessary to enable the *Styles* RTE Plugin](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/operations/page-authoring/rich-text-editor.html#Enabling%20the%20Style%20Drop-down%20Selector). It took me a lot of reading but I managed to get the *Styles* plugin working.

In way of a *TL;DR* I can only say that the styles configuration follows the same format as in case of Classic UI and that you also need to pay attention to the `uiSettings` for your component as they drive the visibility of buttons in Touch UI.

Here's an example field configuration (rest of the `cq:dialog` omitted for brevity:

```
<text jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
      name="./text"
      sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext"
      useFixedInlineToolbar="true">
    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <format jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" features="*"/>
        <justify jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" features="*"/>
        <lists jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" features="*"/>
        <links jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" features="*"/>
        <styles jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" features="styles">
            <styles jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <warning jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" cssName="warning" text="Warning"/>
                <note jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" cssName="note" text="Note"/>
                <header jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" cssName="header" text="Header"/>
            </styles>
        </styles>
        <paraformat jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" features="*">
            <formats jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <paragraph jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" description="Paragraph" tag="p"/>
                <heading1 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" description="Heading 1" tag="h1"/>
            </formats>
        </paraformat>
    </rtePlugins>
    <uiSettings jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <cui jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <inline jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <popovers jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <justify jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" ref="justify"/>
                    <lists jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" ref="lists"/>
                    <paraformat jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" items="paraformat:getFormats:paraformat-pulldown" ref="paraformat"/>
                    <styles jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" items="styles:getStyles:styles-pulldown" ref="styles"/>
                </popovers>
            </inline>
        </cui>
    </uiSettings>
</text>
```

Note the elements in `text/rtePlugins/styles` and `text/uiSettings/cui/inline/popovers/styles`.

Here's how it looks on the page:

[image: Example styles dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
<rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <styles
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                features="*">
        <styles jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <style1
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        cssName="style1"
                                        text="style1"/>
            <style2
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        cssName="style2"
                                        text="style2"/>
            <section--title>
            </styles>
        </styles>
    </rtePlugins>
```