# How to use external style sheets in AEM RTE component

Tags: aem

Since AEM RTE styles only works with predefined classes how can we add dynamic styling to a section of page. Like I want to do something like this but its stripping off anything in style attribute after the first one. Like from the div style only background is preserved and other attributes are stripped off.

```
<div style="background: #f4f4f4 ; border: 2 ; padding: 15 15 15 15 ; box-shadow: 5px 5px #a79d97 ; border-radius: 8px;">
<h3>
<span class="large">Managing Support Contacts and Account Access within XXX from April 19th !!</span>
</h3>
<p>We are excited to release an update to XXX to help Support Administrators manage the support contacts who have access to their accounts. This new tab will enable access permissions for each contact.</p>
<p>
<span class="btn" style="background: #213c60; color: white; border: 1;">Show Me More</span>
</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Touch UI and AEM 6.2 -> Yes, you can have external stylesheets and add custom classes to style RTE elements. Styles plugin helps you with this. This [helpx](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/administering/using/rich-text-editor.html#StylesText) doc details all the steps required. It essentially involves -

- Activating the styles plugin for the style option to appear in the RTE dialog.
- Location reference of external style sheet.
- Defining custom classes to target elements in RTE.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42181671/4173416) for the sample dialog.xml

If you are using Touch UI and on AEM 6.0, this is not supported OOTB.